# How jquery widget works

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i was working with jquery widget and seeing few examples on it.

```
$.widget("custom.progressbar", {
    options : {
        value : 0
    },
    _create : function() {
        var progress = this.options.value + "%";
        this.element.addClass("progressbar").text(progress);
    },
    // Create a public method.
    value : function(value) {
        // No value passed, act as a getter.
        if (value === undefined) {
            return this.options.value;
        }
        // Value passed, act as a setter.
        this.options.value = this._constrain(value);
        var progress = this.options.value + "%";
        this.element.text(progress);
    },
    // Create a private method.
    _constrain : function(value) {
        if (value > 100) {
            value = 100;
        }
        if (value < 0) {
            value = 0;
        }
        return value;
    }
});
```

calling widget

```
var bar = $("<div></div>").appendTo("body").progressbar({
    value : 20
});
// Get the current value.
alert(bar.progressbar("value"));
// Update the value.
bar.progressbar("value", 50);
// Get the current value again.
alert(bar.progressbar("value"));
```

i want to understand how it is defining custom.progressbar as progressbar(..) function.

Comment: This code uses the jQuery widget factory, so I suggest you read up on that. http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/how-to-use-the-widget-factory/

Comment: in the jquery widget definition the prefixes are ignored - it is used only for naming convention

Comment: may i call custom.progressbar(...)? valid